# Convert Hexadecimal to Binary (large values)

Tags: ios, binary, hex

```
-(NSString *)toBinary:(NSUInteger)input
{
    if (input == 1 || input == 0)
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", input];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%u", [self toBinary:input / 2], input % 2];
}

NSString *hex = txtHexInput.text;
NSUInteger hexAsInt;
[[NSScanner scannerWithString:hex] scanHexInt:&hexAsInt];
NSString *binary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self toBinary:hexAsInt]];
txtBinaryInput.text = binary;
```

The above code works great... that is until you need to exceed 32 bits. Any pointers to converting hex to binary for larger than 32 bit values? Thank you.

Comment: Use `uint64_t` to get 64 bits. Beyond that you need to describe how you get larger integers.

Comment: I'm looking into this now... is there an efficient way to incorporate that into my current code?

Answer (score 2):

You can get 64 bits using `uint64_t` or `unsigned long long`.

```
-(NSString *)toBinary:(unsigned long long)input
{
    if (input == 1 || input == 0)
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%llu", input];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%llu", [self toBinary:input / 2], input % 2];
}

NSString *hex = txtHexInput.text;
unsigned long long hexAsULL;
[[NSScanner scannerWithString:hex] scanHexLongLong:&hexAsULL];
NSString *binary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self toBinary:hexAsULL]];
txtBinaryInput.text = binary;
```

This will give you numbers from 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 (decimal)

Comment: Oh thank you! I was working along those lines but did not finish it off correctly. I changed the %ull to %llu.